# Arch Linux Install on Macbook Pro 2017 Model

Tags: linux, arch-linux, system-installation, resolution, cfdisk

My end goal here is to install Arch Linux on my Macbook Pro. I am trying to use cfdisk but can not see the bottom of the screen. I can not change the resolution of the screen. I am have tried plugging in a HDMI to USB-C cable and tried on a monitor but I can not still see the full page. I have heard that you can sometimes pass an argument on the install so that you can change the resolution but I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This repository [the state of Linux on MacBook 2016 & 2017](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux) contains various problems encountered with installing and running Linux on MBP.

You can reference the bug list and solution on the various linked articles.

[Extracted quote below](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7#gistcomment-1979652)

> Regarding the screen resolution issue: That appears to be a bug in the EDID data provided by the display. Happens on the 13,2 as well (https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux#screen). It could also be that the displays have a higher resolution as advertised, but as Xorg correctly probes the right resolution I suspect it is a bug.
>
> Hardware accelerated graphics output is also no problem with the integrated intel graphics card on the MacBookPro13,2. I just had to force Xorg to pick the `intel` driver (with Debian). I did a quick try with `0ad` and that runs really smooth with >50fps with the highest graphical details and native screen resolution.
> Settings the screen brightness works also out of the box with Debian. The UX isn't that nice, as there are no dedicated keys for doing it, as the Touch Bar isn't working yet and the integrated ambient light sensor isn't working either yet. But in KDE I can easily change it via the power management settings.
>
> I have the problem from time to time that NVMe isn't properly working at boot and I have to restart to get it working. Do you have the same issue as well? I thought it could be related to the queue depth-related workaround from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.10-rc5/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c#L1619 which is in place for the MacBook8,1, but not yet for the MacBookPro13,x, but I haven't tried it out yet.